# Django template if statement always evaluates to true

Tags: django, templates, if-statement, block, conditional-statements

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward, but for some reason I am unable to solve this problem. I'm using Django 1.4. I am trying to do a basic check to see if a <strike>list</strike> QuerySet is empty or not during template rendering, but the if statement I'm using seems always to evaluate to true.

I have a Django template that reads:

```
{% extends 'includes/base.html' %}

{% if object_list %}
...
{% block data %}
   {% for object in object_list %}
     ...
     {{ object.create_date }}
     ...
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock data %}
...
{% endif %}
```

'base.html' has the block:

```
<body>
{% block content %}
  ...   
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      {% block data %}
      <div align="center"><i>No data.</i></div>
      {% endblock data %}
    </div><!-- span12 -->
  </div><!-- row -->
{% endblock content %}
...
</body>
```

The view function generating the QuerySet is here:

```
def barcode_track(request, model):
    query = request.GET.get('barcode_search', '')
    object_list = model.objects.all()
    if query:
        object_list = model.objects.filter(barcode__icontains=query)
    return render_to_response('barcode_track/barcode_list.html',
                              {'object_list': object_list, 'query': query},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Which is called via this form:

```
<form id="barcode_search_form" method="get" action="" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="barcode_search" value="{{ query }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

And the urls.py line:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('barcode_track.views',
                       url(r'^$', 'barcode_track', {'model': Barcode},
                           name="barcode_track"),)
```

The idea is that results will only be presented if they exist in `object_list`, and otherwise the parent block will remain unaltered. I have tried changing the name of `object_list`, and I have printed `{{ dicts }}` to the page to ensure that `object_list` is, in fact, empty (which it is). I am not using a generic view, although I realize that the name suggests as much. I have actually had this trouble in a different app I wrote using similar logic, so I must be doing something systematically incorrectly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is `object_list` a Python's `list` or some other data structure?

Comment: How are you generating `object_list`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that; object_list is technically a Django QuerySet (from SomeModel.objects.filter() or .all())

Comment: Can you also add in your `view function` to your question? It will help to see exactly how you are building your `queryset` in your `view function`.

Comment: yes, the view function will be helpful. please do

Comment: Added the view. I appreciate the help, everyone. I've learned Django sort of haphazardly so I still feel I'm missing some of the underlying logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't wrap control flow tags like `if` around a `block`. Your problem is that the child template's definition for block `data` is being used simply because it's there.

You can fix it by placing the `if` tag inside `block data`. If you want to inherit the parent's contents when the list is empty, add an `else` case that expands to `{{ block.super }}`.

Comment: Ah! That does it. Thank you all for your help!