# Removing element from for loop html django?

Tags: django

I have a for loop in my html to show the user their favourite games.
Like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-cart-products">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% for i in wishlist %}
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-details">
            <h4 class="product-title">
                <a href="{% url 'detail' i.oyunlar.platformurl i.oyunlar.slugyap %}">{{i.oyunlar.title}}
                    {{i.oyunlar.platform}}</a>
            </h4>

            <span class="cart-product-info">
                <!--    <span class="cart-product-qty">1</span>-->
                    Anlık en ucuz Fiyatı: {{i.oyunlar.en_ucuz}}
                </span>
        </div><!-- End .product-details -->

        <figure class="product-image-container">
            <a href="{% url 'detail' i.oyunlar.platformurl i.oyunlar.slugyap %}"
                class="product-image">
                <img src=" {{i.oyunlar.image}}" alt="product">
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote1').submit()}" class="btn-remove" title="Favorilerden Çıkar"><i
                    class="icon-retweet"></i></a>
            <form id="upvote1" method="POST" action="{% url 'favhome' i.oyunlar.game_id %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}

            </form>

        </figure>
    </div><!-- End .product -->
    {% endfor %}
```

I am trying to remove element like this:

```
form id="upvote1" method="POST" action="{% url 'favhome' i.oyunlar.game_id %}">
                                                  {% csrf_token %}

                                            </form>
```

The problem is that I can only remove first element in this loop cannot remove the second one third one or last one. How can I change my code to remove the selected element?

Comment: you mean removing on the frontend? or in the database?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421606/django-strange-template-conditional-rendering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate identifiers for your html elements. *They all use "upvote1"*

You can used `{{ forloop.counter }}` to provide an unique enumeration identifier for your elements.

```html
<a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote{{ forloop.counter }}').submit()}" class="btn-remove" title="Favorilerden Çıkar"><i class="icon-retweet"></i></a>
<form id="upvote{{ forloop.counter }}" method="POST" action="{% url 'favhome' i.oyunlar.game_id %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

> *Note: you can use the models `id` also if this is unique. **e.g. {{ i.id }}***